# How to generate PublishedContentModels DLL if you can't build because of missing PublishedContentModels

Tags: umbraco7

I inherited an Umbraco 7 VS solution where all Umbraco packages are conveniently added through nuget, along with a dump of the database.

I figured I'd have no trouble getting it to build, but I'm a bit stuck on the Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels. This file wasn't included in source control, and was added as a reference for the main web project and another supporting project. In the web.config the ModelsBuilder Modelsmode is set to `<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />` .

Obviously if I could open the web project, I could generate the Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels assembly, but I can't because the project won't build because of the missing Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels assembly. 
The model builder VS plugin is also just a frontend for the web interface, so that won't work.

This seems like a Catch-22 situation. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using the following steps:

- Downloaded a fresh Umbraco site, exact same version, from Umbraco
- Edited the web.config to point to my existing database
- Changed the ModelsMode for the ModelsBuilder in the Web.config (`<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />`)
- Copied most of the bin folder of the original site to the new site
- This allowed me to generate **a** Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll. It wasn't quite the same, but with some minor changes I could get it to build
- Once it builds, regenerate the original Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll and undo the changes

In conclusion; don't lose that file.